# What is the significance of the $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ subgroup of $SO(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-cohomology

If one thinks of $SO(3)$ as the rotations in three-dimensional space, then the $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ subgroup is given by the 180 degree rotations along three perpendicular axes (which indeed commute).

On a mathematical level this just seems like --at least on first sight-- one of the many [finite subgroups of $SO(3)$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R)). However, I am a physicist, and there this subgroup plays an important role. In particular, physicists are interested in the fact that $H^2_\textrm{group}(SO(3);U(1)) \cong H^2_\textrm{group}(\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2; U(1))$, i.e. if one is interested in the distinct classes of projective representations of $SO(3)$, it is sufficient to focus on $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2 \subset SO(3)$. (This ties into something physicists call topological phases of matter; in fact this particular piece of math is relevant for the recent Nobel prize.) So at least *from this perspective*, $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ can be seen as a sort of `skeleton' of $SO(3)$ (in purely figurative language).

So I was wondering: is there something mathematically significant about the $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ subgroup of $SO(3)$? I.e. is there some natural characterization which defines it as a subgroup, leading to a notion that is applicable to more general groups? (Or is the fact that it is has the same [second] group cohomology simply an uninteresting and limited curiosity?) Is its relation to the generators of $SO(3)$ of particular importance?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it $H^2(SO(3),U(1))=H^2(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2,U(1))$? Perhaps the reasoning applies to the other "finite Clifford groups" inside the $SO(n)$s mentioned by Mikhail in his answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get a $Z_2\times Z_2$ embedded in $SO(3)$ also via the Klein subgroup of $S_4$ and observe that $S_4$ is the group of symmetries of the regular tetrahedron.

In the book *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn, on pages 36-37 the authors discuss the finite *Clifford group* $F_n$ associated with the Clifford algebra $Cl(n)$, as well as the relation between their representations. Since Clifford algebras and matrix algebras are closely related (see e.g., the table on page 29 there), there is a good chance that one might be able to view the Klein subgroup or a suitable extension thereof as the Clifford group of an appropriate algebra, and thereby obtain a connection between their representations.

Comment: 180-degree rotations correspond to diagonal matrices.

Comment: @ErickWong, good point.

Comment: By $S_3$ you mean $S_4$, surely? Also, I'm pretty sure this is the exact same subgroup. You're rotating around the lines joining midpoints of opposite edges of the tetrahedron; those lines are mutually perpendicular.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, thanks.

Comment: Specifically, if you take the tetrahedron to be the one with vertices at $(-1,-1,1)$, $(-1,1,-1)$, $(1,-1,-1)$, and $(1,1,1)$, and have $A_4$ correspond to the rotations of that tetrahedron, then the Klein subgroup of that $A_4$ is _exactly_ the $180^\circ$ rotations around the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-axes.